# Drawing Oval on canvas with PAINT object in Android

Tags: android, canvas, drawing, paint

In the following code, I'm trying to draw an oval which be enlarged with time.

```
Bitmap currBitmap = null;
Canvas currCanvas = null;

//Config Paint Case2
final Paint currPaint = new Paint();
List BlocksList = null;
boolean bSet = false;

public void DrawOval(Bitmap src, int nRadiusprct) 
{
    // image size
    int width = src.getWidth();
    int height = src.getHeight();

    //create bitmap output
    if(currBitmap  == null)
        currBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    // set canvas for painting
    if(currCanvas == null)
    {
        currCanvas = new Canvas(currBitmap);
        currCanvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        MainActivity.imgMain.setImageBitmap(currBitmap);
    }

    // config paint Case1
    /*final Paint currPaint = new Paint();
    currPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    currPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);*/

    // config paint Case2
    if(!bSet)
    {
        currPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        currPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        // create Xfer mode
         currPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        bSet = true;
    }

    // config rectangle for embedding
    int nMidWidth = width/2;
    int nMidHeight = height/2;
    float fPercent = (nRadiusprct / 100.0f);

    float fLeft = nMidWidth * (1 - fPercent);  
    float fRight = nMidWidth * (1 + fPercent);
    float fTop = nMidHeight * (1 - fPercent);
    float fBottom = nMidHeight * (1 + fPercent);

    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(fLeft, fTop, fRight, fBottom);

    currCanvas.drawOval(rectF, currPaint);

    // create Xfer mode, Config Paint Case1
    //currPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));

    currCanvas.drawBitmap(src, rect, rect, currPaint);

    MainActivity.imgMain.invalidate();
}
```

Now, As you can see write a comment "Config Paint Case1" or "Config Paint Case2", case1 represents the case where I create a paint instance each time the method is called, while case 2 represents where I define a member object in the class so I can use it whenever I need, the problem that when I'm using the first case everything is working perfectly and accurate, while when I'm using the second case nothing happened, The main thing that in my opinion I don't need to create a paint object each time so I need to optimize my code more and more, but why this happened here.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got an answer to this question, A great help by this article [Transparency with JPEGs done right](http://www.piwai.info/transparent-jpegs-done-right/) that describes how PorterDuff modes are work, In that article I found this [Xfermodes Example](https://gitorious.org/freebroid/development/source/62e92d7a2a3fd2798901ec2e7c452ff0e4067163:samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/Xfermodes.java#L162) which gives me where is the error and here is the description.

Actually, I don't need to create a paint object everytime, what I need is to deal with the xfermodes in a correct way, the perfect code is:

```
 Bitmap currBitmap = null;
 Canvas currCanvas = null;

 //Config Paint Case2
 final Paint currPaint = new Paint();
 List BlocksList = null;
 boolean bSet = false;

public void DrawOval(Bitmap src, int nRadiusprct) 
{
    // image size
    int width = src.getWidth();
    int height = src.getHeight();

    //create bitmap output
    if(currBitmap  == null)
        currBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    // set canvas for painting
    if(currCanvas == null)
    {
        currCanvas = new Canvas(currBitmap);
        MainActivity.imgMain.setImageBitmap(currBitmap);
    }

    // config paint Case2
    if(!bSet)
    {
        currPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        currPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        bSet = true;
    }

    // config rectangle for embedding
    int nMidWidth = width/2;
    int nMidHeight = height/2;
    float fPercent = (nRadiusprct / 100.0f);

    float fLeft = nMidWidth * (1 - fPercent);  
    float fRight = nMidWidth * (1 + fPercent);
    float fTop = nMidHeight * (1 - fPercent);
    float fBottom = nMidHeight * (1 + fPercent);

    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(fLeft, fTop, fRight, fBottom);

    Xfermode BeforEPaintXferMode = currPaint.getXfermode();

    currCanvas.drawOval(rectF, currPaint);

    // create Xfer mode
    currPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));

    // draw source image to canvas
    currCanvas.drawBitmap(src, rect, rect, currPaint);

    currPaint.setXfermode(BeforEPaintXferMode);

    MainActivity.imgMain.invalidate();
}
```

Now, as you can see I just storing the current xfermode before painting, then I set it to SRC_IN mode and finally, I go back to the original one. and everything is working perfectly.